# Nativescript custom functions

Tags: angular, function, nativescript

I create some functions and import its module, on app.component.ts file, I need to use these functions on other app components. How to do that ?

For example: I want to create custom alert message function, and use it in all other pages.

Thanks

Comment: You can create services and use them across the components in your module via dependency injection. This is pretty much the standard Angular way and not related to NativeScript (I am assuming that you are using nativescript+angular as you have tagged angular)

Comment: Many thanks @NickIliev, I do it.

Answer (score 0):

create this function in a service so you can make the function in all your components just import the service and in app.module you have to do this

```
providers: [YourService],
```